# Entity tries to insert in a column for each item in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity

I have several associated objects that I'm trying to insert into several tables with the entity framework, and Entity is trying to insert all the items in a list into several different (non-existent) columns automatically.

The problem is with the property `public List<ApprovalStage> Stages`, which entity throws  this error:

`{"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."}`

The inner exception is:

`{"Invalid column name 'ApprovalStage_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'ApprovalStage_Id1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'ApprovalStage_Id2'."}`

I reduced the number of objects in the list, and retried to verify that it was indeed trying to insert each item in the list into its own column.

Here are the objects in question:

```
public class ComplexApprovalProcess
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public List<ApprovalStage> Stages { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Form")]
    public long FormId { get; set; }
    public FormBase Form { get; set; }

    bool Approved { get; set; }

    bool Denied { get; set; }

    private bool CheckCompleted() {

        foreach (ApprovalStage stage in this.Stages)
        {
            if (stage.Completed == false)
            {
                //if any stage is incomplete, the process is not complete
                return false;
            }
        }
        //no stages incomplete means all stages complete
        return true;
    }

    public static ComplexApprovalProcess CreateCheckRequestApprovalProcess(FormBase form)
    {
        UsersModel user = null;

        ComplexApprovalProcess process = new ComplexApprovalProcess();

        using (TechnologyProjectPlanContext db = new TechnologyProjectPlanContext())
        {
            int id = SessionVar.Get<int>(SessionVar.USERID);

            user = db.UsersModels.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        process.Form = form;

        ApprovalStage InitialReview = new ApprovalStage();
        InitialReview.Approvers = new List<Approver>();
        InitialReview.Advisors = new List<Approver>();
        InitialReview.Viewers = new List<Approver>();

        InitialReview.ApprovalProcess = process;
        InitialReview.Approvers.Add(new Approver(user, form, InitialReview));
        InitialReview.Advisors.Add(new Approver(user, form, InitialReview));
        InitialReview.Viewers.Add(new Approver(user, form, InitialReview));
        InitialReview.StageName = "Initial Review";

        //ApprovalStage MiddleApproval = new ApprovalStage();
        //MiddleApproval.Approvers = new List<Approver>();
        //MiddleApproval.Advisors = new List<Approver>();
        //MiddleApproval.Viewers = new List<Approver>();

        //MiddleApproval.ApprovalProcess = process;
        //MiddleApproval.Approvers.Add(new Approver(user, form, MiddleApproval));
        //MiddleApproval.Advisors.Add(new Approver(user, form, MiddleApproval));
        //MiddleApproval.Viewers.Add(new Approver(user, form, MiddleApproval));
        //MiddleApproval.StageName = "Middle Approval";


        ApprovalStage FinalApproval = new ApprovalStage();
        FinalApproval.Approvers = new List<Approver>();
        FinalApproval.Advisors = new List<Approver>();
        FinalApproval.Viewers = new List<Approver>();

        FinalApproval.ApprovalProcess = process;
        FinalApproval.Approvers.Add(new Approver(user, form, FinalApproval));
        FinalApproval.Advisors.Add(new Approver(user, form, FinalApproval));
        FinalApproval.Viewers.Add(new Approver(user, form, FinalApproval));
        FinalApproval.StageName = "Final Approval";

        process.Stages = new List<ApprovalStage>();
        process.Stages.AddRange(new ApprovalStage[] { InitialReview, FinalApproval });

        //set default values
        process.Approved = false;
        process.Denied = false;

        return process;
    }
    public void SaveToDb()
    {
        //make sure we have at least one stage and either a form reference (new form) or form id (old form) before moving forward
        if ((Stages != null && Stages.Count > 0) && (Form != null || FormId > 0))
        { 
            using (TechnologyProjectPlanContext  db = new TechnologyProjectPlanContext())
            {
                db.ComplexApprovalProcesses.Add(this);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
}

public class ApprovalStage
{
    //Each stage requires at least one approver
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApprovalProcess")]
    public long ApprovalProcessId { get; set; }

    public ComplexApprovalProcess ApprovalProcess { get; set; }

    public List<Approver> Approvers { get; set; } //These users are required to approve before the form can move to the next stage.

    public List<Approver> Advisors { get; set; } //These users can see the form and approve at this stage, but they are not required.

    public List<Approver> Viewers { get; set; } //These users can see the form, but cannot approve

    public string StageName { get; set; } //Name of stage e.g. Review, Final Approval, etc.  Gives a custom feel?

    public void Approve()
    {
        this.Completed = true;
        this.Approved = true;
        //just to make sure
        this.Denied = false;
    }

    public void Deny()
    {
        this.Completed = true;
        this.Denied = true;
        //just to make sure
        this.Approved = false;
    }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public bool Approved { get; set; }

    public bool Denied { get; set; }

    public bool CanAbstain { get; set; }

    public ApprovalStage()
    { 
        //just set some defaults, like approval stages should not be complete when constructed
        this.Approved = false;
        this.Denied = false;
        this.Completed = false;
    }

}

public class Approver
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public UsersModel User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Form")]
    public long FormId { get; set; }

    public FormBase Form { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Stage")]
    public long StageId { get; set; }

    public ApprovalStage Stage { get; set; }

    public bool Approved { get; set; }

    public bool Denied { get; set; }

    public bool Abstain { get; set; }

    private void checkCompletion() 
    {
        bool allApproved = true;

        bool oneDenied = false;

        foreach (Approver approver in this.Stage.Approvers)
        {
            if (!approver.Approved)
            {
                allApproved = false;
            }
            if (approver.Denied)
            {
                oneDenied = true;
            }
        }

        if (allApproved)
        {
            this.Stage.Approve();
        }
        if (oneDenied)
        {
            this.Stage.Deny();
        }
        else
        { 
            //outcome still uncertain, do nothing
        }
    }

    public void Approve()
    {
        this.Approved = true;
        this.Denied = false;

        checkCompletion();
    }

    public void Deny()
    {
        this.Denied = true;
        this.Approved = false;

        checkCompletion();
    }

    public Approver() { }

    public Approver(UsersModel user, FormBase form, ApprovalStage stage)
    {
        this.Stage = stage;
        this.User = user;
        this.Form = form;
        this.Approved = false;
        this.Denied = false;
        this.Abstain = false;
    }
}
```

It seems like Entity doesn't understand that the objects in `List<ApprovalStage> Stages` will refer back to the `ComplexApprovalProcess`, and the `ComplexApprovalProcess` doesn't need to refer forward to the `ApprovalStages`

**Edit:** Really need help with this if anyone can spare the time!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I never solved that problem, but I just broke each object apart and saved them separately with Ids instead of letting Entity do it.